# tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My structure is the following:

`UIViewController -> UIVIew -> UITableView`

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`

and

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

is called but

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

is not called.

```
class ViewcontrollerA : UIViewController  , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.doctortableView.delegate = self
        self.doctortableView.dataSource = self
        self.doctortableView.allowsSelection = true

    }

    func callTable() {

        doctortableView.frame = CGRect(......)
        view1.addSubview(doctortableView)
        doctortableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.view.addSubview(view1)

    }

    // Tableview Functions

    // Number of Sections in Table
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var count = Int()

        return count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //This function is not called
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not being called, you're data source doesn't have any rows?

Comment: It is amazing how quick a ton of answers appeared that all apparently were attracted by "some tableview delegate method not being called" and instead of looking at the code all just assumed OP missed hooking the delegate up correctly.

Comment: @luk2302 I really don't understand , why does people reply before reading the full question.

Comment: Because the first poster "wins", in case they would have got it right the one person posting the answer the fastest would presumable get the most upvotes / accepted.

Comment: @swiftuser123  DO you have any Gesture added ?

Comment: @MikeAlter no I don't have Gesture here.

Comment: @swiftuser123 are other delegate called not **datasource** methods ?

Comment: @MikeAlter Data source methods are called , but Delegate methods are not called.

Comment: Not a single delegate ? like `heightForRowAt` ,`willDisplay` ?, It is quite surprising you have already set delgate = self, And you are able to scroll Tableview means it is already in front

Comment: ya you are guessing correctly. I am not able to scroll my tableview. Is this the problem because tableview is  on top of UIView?

Comment: Yes You need to put it on top,

Comment: what do you mean ? UIViewController -> UIVIew -> UITableView it is like this now.

Comment: I have posted how to do it , Check it and let me know if it is helping or not ? , Before you ask such a question try to  google may save your time & Reputation and other's too

Comment: I tried `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: doctortableView)`  its not working

Comment: Anyways Thank you.

Comment: try to set self.view.clipsTOBound = true and same for table and check you are able to see tableview ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be in this datasource method at first glance.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var count = Int()

    return count
}
```

Doesn't `Int()` return 0? That means your tableview doesn't have any cells.

Comment: @Jeremy you should not write whole error method, instead write this method with rectifications.

Comment: I have a dictionary data, I just did not mention this objects here. I do get display of my data in Tableview . Problem is i can not select the rows.

Comment: @swiftuser123 No, the data cannot be displayed if your row count is 0. So either you didn't show us the real code you're using, or what you just said is wrong. In both cases, please don't. This specific issue has been answered. If you have a new issue related to this code, *ask a new question*. Jeremy here has already answered the current question.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion on Chat

You are creating `TableView` programatically and add to self.view

```
func callTable() {

    doctortableView.frame = CGRect(......)
    view1.addSubview(doctortableView)
    doctortableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.view.addSubview(view1)

}
```

but your tableView is not on top, so you are not able to scroll it and that's why delegate are not working 
 following line  is missing

> self.view.bringSubview(toFront: doctortableView)

Here is Full code

```
func callTable() {

    doctortableView.frame = CGRect(......)
    view1.addSubview(doctortableView)
    doctortableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.view.addSubview(view1)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: doctortableView)

}
```